# Call to function() blocked by CSP even after adding 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy

I am working on a NodeJS Project and I'm using `CSP` ([Content Security Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/)).

I'm using a external plugin `FullCalendar` which is being blocked by csp giving the following error:

`Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP`

I use `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';` to override it but did not work in  firefox. In other browser it is working fine.

I got stuck on this issue by 4h.

It would be helpful to get the solution.

I am using the following format in CSP restrictions.

> X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline img-src *;options eval-script;
>   X-WebKit-CSP: default-src *;  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline img-src *;
>   Content-Security-Policy:  default-src *;  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline img-src *;

Comment: do you want to use `eval` function in CSP?

Comment: not getting any other alternative rather than using so yes i want to use `eval` function.@VarunMalhotra

Comment: I'm going to answer a more appropriate use of `eval` rather than using `eval` directly in CSP which is depreciated or violates `CSP` rules.

Comment: ok no problem i will try with that one also..

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? Your policies look solid to me :-/ Although the 'unsafe-eval' in the X-Content-Security-Policy header is invalid, maybe that's causing the issue. Anecdotally I've had more success using 'allow' over default-src for FF < 23.

Comment: I am using FF22 and can u suggest me the valid 'unsafe-eval' in the X-Content-Security-Policy header to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

assuming `this.disp` is containing the expression to be evaluated. Also `disp: document.getElementById("id_of_text_input_field")`. For eg. this.disp.value = `123/45*67+8-9%10`. It will also care for `negative` nos. For eg. `-123+3` = `-120`. Yay!

```
compute: function compute() {

  var sign = 1;
  if (this.disp.value[0] == '-') sign = -1;
  this.disp.value = this.calculate(this.disp.value,sign);
  this.update(this.disp.value.length);
  return this.disp.value;
  },

  calculate: function calculate(input,sign){

   var opr_list = { add : '+'
           , sub : '-' 
           , div : '/'
           , mlt : '*'
           , mod : '%'
            };

   opr_list.opr = [[ [opr_list.mlt] , [opr_list.div] , [opr_list.mod]],
            [ [opr_list.add] , [opr_list.sub] ]];

   input = input.replace(/[^0-9%^*\/()\-+.]/g,'');      

   var output,n;
   for(var i=0, n=opr_list.opr.length; i<n; i++ ){

      var re = new RegExp('(\\d+\\.?\\d*)([\\'+opr_list.opr[i].join('\\')+'])(\\d+\\.?\\d*)');
      re.lastIndex = 0;                                     
            while( re.test(input) ){

         output = this.compute_result(opr_list,sign*RegExp.$1,RegExp.$2,RegExp.$3);

         if (isNaN(output) || !isFinite(output)) return output; 
         input  = input.replace(re,output);
      }
   }

   return output;
},

   compute_result: function compute_result(opr_list,a,op,b){
      a=a*1; b=b*1;
      switch(op){
         case opr_list.add: return a+b; break;
         case opr_list.sub: return a-b; break;
         case opr_list.div: return a/b; break;
         case opr_list.mlt: return a*b; break;
         case opr_list.mod: return a%b; break;
         default: null;
      }
   }
```

You can add more **operators** and **cases** as per your requirements. For eg. Square, `x^y`, etc.

Comment: Dude i am not using any `eval()` here i am getting a function blocked in csp which comes under `eval script base restriction` got suggestion that we should use `unsafe-eval & unsafe-inline` but for me it is not working so asking for any other alternatives...

Comment: Oh, you may contact Mozilla developers on irc. They will help you getting out.

Comment: any luck with contacting firefox devs regarding thigs?

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest way I found on the Internet.
Embed Meta tag in your index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="
        default-src *
        style-src * 'unsafe-inline'
        script-src *
        img-src * data:
        'unsafe-eval'
        " />
```

This will allow to render and use of metafiles like Images, JavaScript, CSS from other source or platform.

Comment: This is dangerous; unsafe-eval is a common cause of XSS attacks. Much better to remove the use of eval/Function constructor than allow eval from any source.